# How is locate command different from find command?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I have used both `find` and `locate` command for searching the absolute path of a file or directory, though in some systems I have found `locate` not working.

Can someone explain how differently they work?

And what does the `updatedb` command do in context of `locate` command.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is better on either superuser or unix.se, and I believe it has already been answered on both.

Answer (score 2):

`locate` builds an index first of your file system first to perform indexed search.

`find` does not. It performs the search on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

The [updatedb(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/updatedb) command is updating (or creating) some caching information about file paths on your file system. The [locate(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/locate) command is using that cache.

You should learn to use and read man pages (like the ones I linked above). Install the `manpages` and `manpages-dev` packages and type `man man` to start.